# MVC - Moq Unit Test FileContentResult (ActionResult) - NullRefernceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

So I'm posting to an MVC controller, which makes a call to a repository to get a Telerik report, then exports a PDF.  I'm having trouble unit testing this and keep getting an error -

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Controller**

```
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    private IPDFRepository _pdfRepository;

    //Dependency Injection using Unity.MVC5 NuGet Package
    public ReportController(IPDFRepository pdfRepository)
    {
        _pdfRepository = pdfRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult PDFExport(PDFViewModel model)
    {
        byte[] report = _pdfRepository.BuildExport(model);
        return File(report, "application/pdf", model.SelectedReport + ".pdf");
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Report_PDFExport_Returns_ActionResult()
{
    //Arrange
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IPDFRepository>();
    mockRepository.Setup(x => x.BuildExport(It.IsAny<PDFViewModel>()));

    ReportController controller = new ReportController(mockRepository.Object);

    //Act
    ActionResult result = controller.PDFExport(It.IsAny<PDFViewModel>());

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ActionResult));
}
```

Now, I realize this has something to do with this return portion of my controller.

```
return File(report, "application/pdf", model.SelectedReport + ".pdf");
```

I can change that around to return string, test again and get this to work.

Also, if I comment out these last two lines of the unit test,

```
//Act
//ActionResult result = controller.PDFExport(It.IsAny<PDFViewModel>());

//Assert
//Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ActionResult));
```

it will run without error.  I can't figure out how to get around the null reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting up the mock of `IPDFRepository` properly. It needs to configure what it is going to return when `BuildExport` is called. Otherwise `report` will be `null`.

And you are also not calling the method under test with a valid parameter. You need to create a concrete instance other wise the model will be `null` and `model.SelectedReport` with error out.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Report_PDFExport_Returns_ActionResult()
{
    //Arrange
    byte[] fakePDFReport = new byte[0];

    var mockRepository = new Mock<IPDFRepository>();
    mockRepository
        .Setup(x => x.BuildExport(It.IsAny<PDFViewModel>()))
        .Returns(fakePDFReport);

    var fakeViewModel = new PDFViewModel {
        SelectedReport = "FakeReportName"
        //Set the needed properties...
    };

    ReportController controller = new ReportController(mockRepository.Object);

    //Act
    ActionResult result = controller.PDFExport(fakeViewModel);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ActionResult));
}
```

Comment: Outstanding.  Thanks for the help.  I was kind of on the right track with trying out something like this on the side, but unit testing is still very new to me.  Very much appreciated.